# Crackling sound when closing 1155 socket

Tags: cpu, computer-building

I am fairly new to assembling PCs but this time I decided to assemble it all by myself.

I'm trying to install my CPU in socket 1155 on my Asus motherboard and while I'm closing the socket, there is a slight crackling sound going on.

Is this normal? Should it be completely silent, or is it okay for pins to crack just a little? (it sound like stepping on sand on the floor or something like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is normal. There was a small sound even at the s478 back then.

Since they changed it up at the s775 (there are no "legs" on the 775 like there was on the 478, so you can't really go wrong when you install a "modern" CPU. 775 and above got only)

[image]

Just to make sure, you can make a picture of the mainboard's LGA and add it as a comment ... but if the PC works ... I'm sure there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: So this crackling doesn't mean that pins are bending somehow? Will I be able to use this socket again if I decide to unplug this CPU and put another one in?

Comment: No, no of course not. First, you cannot insert it in a wrong way. Second, there is a golden arrow (http://bit.ly/oLLpxR) on the CPU, and there is a pin left in the socket. That's where the arrow should point. - And yeah, just remove the current one. HOWEVER: Always remove the thermal paste from the old one (both cpu, and clean the socket / cooler) (before you sell it / store it).